# campo editable en bootstraptable con x-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

Estoy usando un bootstrap table del cual quiero modificar una registro de la tabla, para esto estoy usando un complemento que se llama X-Editable ( http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ ) pero el campo editable es un input y necesito que sea un textárea ya que debo introducir saltos de linea en el texto.

Alguien lo ha utilizado que pueda sugerir como hacerlo?

en el código, solo añadi una propiedad a los campos de la tabla que es (data-editable=true):

```
<th data-field="Comments" data-editable="true" data-sortable="true" >Comments</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion, tienes que agregar el atributo `data-type` y especificar `textarea`.  Quedaria asi:

```
<th data-field="Comments" data-editable="true" data-type="textarea" data-sortable="true" >Comments</th>
```

Comment: ya lo intente, pero no funciono..

Comment: Porque no intentas poner un `<a>` dentro del `<th>` y hacer el `<a>` editable?

Comment: algun ejemplo?  no se si te refieras a algo asi:   

<th data-field="Comments"  data-sortable="true"><a data-type="textarea" data-editable="true"></a> Comments </th>... 

pero esto no funciono